# Unittest / Testclass example how to start

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I found this example and I want to make a testclass for this. How do I approach this do I need to make ObjectStructureMap test object? And do I need to make a test object for all the lists? I would appreciate if someone could help me start see:

```
public with sharing class AccountTree{

    public String currentId;
    public List<ObjectStructureMap> asm ;
    public Map<String, ObjectStructureMap> masm;
    public List<Integer> maxLevel;

    public AccountTree() {
        this.asm = new List<ObjectStructureMap>{};
        this.masm = new Map<String, ObjectStructureMap>{};
        this.maxLevel = new List<Integer>{};
    }

    public void setcurrentId( String cid ){
        currentId = cid;
    }

    public List<ObjectStructureMap> getObjectStructure(){
        asm.clear();
        if ( currentId == null ) {
            currentId = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get( 'id' );
        }

        System.assertNotEquals( currentId, null, 'sObject ID must be provided' );
        asm = formatObjectStructure( CurrentId );

        return asm;
    }

    public ObjectStructureMap[] formatObjectStructure( String currentId ){

        List<ObjectStructureMap> asm = new List<ObjectStructureMap>{};
        masm.clear();

        List<Account> al            = new List<Account>{};
        List<ID> currentParent      = new List<ID>{};
        Map<ID, String> nodeList    = new Map<ID, String>{};
        List<String> nodeSortList   = new List<String>{};
        List<Boolean> levelFlag     = new List<Boolean>{};
        List<Boolean> closeFlag     = new List<Boolean>{};
        String nodeId               = '0';
        String nodeType             = 'child';
        Integer count               = 0;
        Integer level               = 0;
        Boolean endOfStructure      = false;

        currentParent.add( GetTopElement( currentId ) );

        while ( !endOfStructure ){

            if( level == 0 ){
                //Change below     
                al = [ SELECT a.Type, a.Site, a.ParentId, a.OwnerId, a.Name, a.Industry, a.Id FROM Account a WHERE a.id IN : CurrentParent ORDER BY a.Name ];
            } 
            else {
                //Change below      
                al = [ SELECT a.Type, a.Site, a.ParentId, a.OwnerId, a.Name, a.Industry, a.Id FROM Account a WHERE a.ParentID IN : CurrentParent ORDER BY a.Name ];
            }

            if( al.size() == 0 ){
                endOfStructure = true;
            }
            else{
                currentParent.clear();
                for ( Integer i = 0 ; i < al.size(); i++ ){
                    //Change below
                    Account a = al[i];
                    nodeId = ( level > 0 ) ? NodeList.get( a.ParentId )+'.'+String.valueOf( i ) : String.valueOf( i );
                    masm.put( NodeID, new ObjectStructureMap( nodeID, levelFlag, closeFlag, nodeType, false, false, a ) );
                    currentParent.add( a.id );
                    nodeList.put( a.id,nodeId );
                    nodeSortList.add( nodeId );
                }

                maxLevel.add( level );                
                level++;
            }
        }

        NodeSortList.sort();
        for( Integer i = 0; i < NodeSortList.size(); i++ ){
            List<String> pnl = new List<String> {};
            List<String> cnl = new List<String> {};
            List<String> nnl = new List<String> {};

            if ( i > 0 ){
                String pn   = NodeSortList[i-1];
                pnl         = pn.split( '\\.', -1 );
            }

            String cn   = NodeSortList[i];
            cnl         = cn.split( '\\.', -1 );

            if( i < NodeSortList.size()-1 ){
                String nn = NodeSortList[i+1];
                nnl = nn.split( '\\.', -1 );
            }

            ObjectStructureMap tasm = masm.get( cn );
            if ( cnl.size() < nnl.size() ){
                //Parent
                tasm.nodeType = ( isLastNode( cnl ) ) ? 'parent_end' : 'parent';
            }
            else if( cnl.size() > nnl.size() ){
                tasm.nodeType   = 'child_end';
                tasm.closeFlag  = setcloseFlag( cnl, nnl, tasm.nodeType );
            }
            else{
                tasm.nodeType = 'child';
            }

            tasm.levelFlag = setlevelFlag( cnl, tasm.nodeType ); 

            //Change below
            if ( tasm.account.id == currentId ) {
                tasm.currentNode = true;
            }
            asm.add( tasm );
        }

        asm[0].nodeType             = 'start';
        asm[asm.size()-1].nodeType  = 'end';

        return asm;
    }

    public List<Boolean> setlevelFlag( List<String> nodeElements, String nodeType ){

        List<Boolean> flagList = new List<Boolean>{};
        String searchNode   = '';
        String workNode     = '';
        Integer cn          = 0;

        for( Integer i = 0; i < nodeElements.size() - 1; i++ ){
            cn = Integer.valueOf( nodeElements[i] );
            cn++;
            searchNode  = workNode + String.valueOf( cn );
            workNode    = workNode + nodeElements[i] + '.';
            if ( masm.containsKey( searchNode ) ){
                flagList.add( true );
            }
            else {
                flagList.add( false );
            }
        }

        return flagList;
    }

    public List<Boolean> setcloseFlag( List<String> cnl, List<String> nnl, String nodeType ){

        List<Boolean> flagList = new List<Boolean>{};
        String searchNode   = '';
        String workNode     = '';
        Integer cn          = 0;

        for( Integer i = nnl.size(); i < cnl.size(); i++ ){
            flagList.add( true );
        }

        return flagList;
    }

    public Boolean isLastNode( List<String> nodeElements ){

        String searchNode   = '';
        Integer cn          = 0;

        for( Integer i = 0; i < nodeElements.size(); i++ ){
            if ( i == nodeElements.size()-1 ){
                cn = Integer.valueOf( nodeElements[i] );
                cn++;
                searchNode = searchNode + String.valueOf( cn );
            }
            else {
                searchNode = searchNode + nodeElements[i] + '.';
            }
        }
        if ( masm.containsKey( searchNode ) ){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    public String GetTopElement( String objId ){

        Boolean top = false;
        while ( !top ) {
            //Change below
            Account a = [ Select a.Id, a.ParentId From Account a where a.Id =: objId limit 1 ];

            if ( a.ParentID != null ) {
                objId = a.ParentID;
            }
            else {
                top = true;
            }
        }
        return objId ;
    }

    public with sharing class ObjectStructureMap{

        public String nodeId;
        public Boolean[] levelFlag = new Boolean[]{};
        public Boolean[] closeFlag = new Boolean[]{};
        public String nodeType;
        public Boolean currentNode;

        public Account account;

        public String getnodeId() { return nodeId; }
        public Boolean[] getlevelFlag() { return levelFlag; }
        public Boolean[] getcloseFlag() { return closeFlag; }
        public String getnodeType() { return nodeType; }
        public Boolean getcurrentNode() { return currentNode; }

        public Account getaccount() { return account; }

        public void setnodeId( String n ) { this.nodeId = n; }
        public void setlevelFlag( Boolean l ) { this.levelFlag.add(l); }
        public void setlcloseFlag( Boolean l ) { this.closeFlag.add(l); }
        public void setnodeType( String nt ) { this.nodeType = nt; }
        public void setcurrentNode( Boolean cn ) { this.currentNode = cn; }

        public void setaccount( Account a ) { this.account = a; }

        public ObjectStructureMap( String nodeId, Boolean[] levelFlag,Boolean[] closeFlag , String nodeType, Boolean lastNode, Boolean currentNode, Account a ){

            this.nodeId         = nodeId;
            this.levelFlag      = levelFlag; 
            this.closeFlag      = closeFlag;
            this.nodeType       = nodeType;
            this.currentNode    = currentNode;

            this.account = a;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if you haven't already, I'd highly suggest going over to Trailhead and going through the [Apex Testing module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing). Trailhead is much better suited than this site is for getting a handle on the basics of various concepts and features.

Putting that aside now, the purpose of unit tests is to exercise a (generally small) portion of your code, **and verify that it behaves the way you think it should**. Verification of results is truly the most important part of a test.

So, the answer to your question "Do I need to make some instances of object XYZ? Do I need to make even more data?" is the always unsatisfying *it depends*.

It all depends on which portion of your code your tests are, well...testing.

Let's take a very simple example

```
public class MyClass{
    public Account myAccount;
    public Integer myInt;

    public MyClass(Integer inputInt){
        this.myInt = inputInt;
    }

    public String getAccountName(){
        return this.myAccount.Name;
    }
}
```

For the above class, if we were to test the constructor, we wouldn't need to set up some test data for a test `Account` because the constructor doesn't use `myAccount` at all.

A test method for the constructor could look like this:

```
@isTest
static void testMyClassConstructor(){
    // Here, testInteger is test data, and is required for this specific test.
    // We need to set up our test data before we can actually execute the piece
    //   of code that we're trying to test.
    Integer testInteger = 5;

    // Using startTest/stopTest isn't required, but it's a good habit to get into.
    // Inside of startTest/stopTest, you are given a separate set of limits, which
    //   can be extremely helpful for more complicated tests that require a lot of setup
    Test.startTest();
    MyClass testInstance = new MyClass(testInteger);
    Test.stopTest();

    // Time to verify results
    // System.assertEquals() and System.assertNotEquals() only _need_ 2 arguments
    //   (expected value, and actual value), but specifying the third parameter
    //   (a specific message to include in case of failure) can be extremely helpful
    //   in figuring out what, precisely, went wrong.
    System.assertEquals(testInteger, testInstance.myInt, 'The integer we passed to the constructor did not match the integer we pulled from the class');
}
```

Testing the `getAccountName()` method is a little different. It does require a test `Account` record to be set up prior to executing the method. If we don't, we'll run into an exception (more on that later).

```
@isTest
static void testGetAccountName(){
    // Again, we do data setup first

    // I could simply set the value of the Account's Name directly in its constructor,
    //   but doing things this way can make a test easier to modify (if you end
    //   up needing to do that), and makes the value we're expecting to see in
    //   our assertion (later on) a bit less 'magical'.
    // (Referring to something as 'magic' means that it seems to appear out of nowhere
    //   with no indication of how the value was chosen, or why it matters.
    //   Relying on magic is generally a bad thing)      
    String testAcctName = 'My Test Account';
    Account testAccount = new Account(Name = testAcctName);

    MyClass testInstance = new MyClass();
    testInstance.myAccount = testAccount;

    Test.startTest();
    String result = testInstance.getAccountName();
    Test.stopTest();

    System.assertEquals(testAcctName, result, 'Account name was different than the name of the Account we set in our test MyClass instance');
}
```

Generally speaking, **if you don't have a test method for every public method that your class exposes, you haven't written enough test methods**. One test per method may not be enough, though.

The test methods so far have been what's called 'happy path' or 'positive case' tests. All of the input has been well-formed, and we've provided exactly what the class needs to run. The real world is not so kind. It is also a good idea to write tests that exercise what happens in 'negative cases', when some vital data is missing.

For this simple class, one possible 'negative case' would be calling `getAccountName()` without first setting the `myAccount` class variable first.

```
@isTest
static void testGetAccountNameNoAccountGiven(){
    MyClass testInstance = new MyClass();

    Test.startTest();
    String result = testInstance.getAccountName();
    Test.stopTest();

    // There isn't really much of anything we can assert against here at the moment...
}
```

If you tried to run that test with the current `getAccountName()` method, the test would fail because `myAccount` is null, and `null.<almost anything>` results in a `NullPointerException`. Even though the test will fail as is, it's a valuable test to have because it has alerted you that there is a situation that the class being tested doesn't currently handle. Writing this test alerted you of this *before your users ran into it*.

Fixing the issue is simple in this case, we just need to add a null check to the method that we were testing

```
public String getAccountName(){
    if(this.myAccount == null){
        return 'There is no Account';
    } else {
        return this.myAccount.Name;
    }
}
```

With this, both tests will pass. Yes, sometimes you will have multiple tests for one method. In this case, instead of the 'unit' being tested being an entire method, the 'unit' is a portion of an individual method.

All of this is also a way to illustrate (admittedly, a bit of a roundabout way to do so) the mindset you need to take when preparing test data. In both `testGetAccountName()` and `testGetAccountNameNoAccount()`, **we execute one part of the if/else statement** and, equally as important, **we set up the test data that was required to ensure that we entered the block that we wanted to test**.

The same idea applies to other situations.

- Want to test that something happens inside of a for loop like `for(Account acct :[SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN :trigger.new])`?

  - Then your test setup needs to insert an `Account` or two so the query actually returns something to loop over.
- Want to test that something special happens when an `Opportunity` is
  owned by a specific user and has a specific value of `StageName`?

  - Then you'll need to create a test `Opportunity` that matches those
    conditions.

To close out, I'll write a sample test for one of the methods in the class you've provided. My answer is long enough as is, so I'll choose one of the simpler methods, `GetTopElement()`.

I see that it requires an `Account` Id, and works to find the `Account` at the top of a hierarchy. For this test, we'll need to create at least 2 test `Accounts`. The class constructor doesn't need anything special.

```
@isTest
static void testGetTopElementHierarchyLevel2(){
    // Set up our test data
    Account parentAccount = new Account(
        Name = 'Test Parent'
    );
    insert parentAccount;

    Account childAccount = new Account(
        Name = 'Test Child', 
        ParentId = parentAccount.Id
    );
    insert childAccount;

    AccountTree testInstance = new AccountTree();

    // Execute our target unit
    Test.startTest();
    String result = testInstance.GetTopElement(childAccount.Id);
    Test.stopTest();

    // Verify results
    System.assertEquals(parentAccount.Id, result, 'The resulting top element Id was not the Id of the Parent Account');
}
```

Hopefully between the Trailhead module and my answer, you'll be able to figure out how to test the rest of your class.

Comment: As a side note, I think that you'll want to re-think your approach for `GetTopElement()`. Queries inside of loops are generally a bad thing, and there are better approaches out there. My answer was, however, getting _really_ long, and I didn't feel that improving the implementation was in the scope of the question at hand.